# OpenCV or other CV for measurement of position in time

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm thinking about using openCV or something like  that for purposes of measuring position (x,y) of physical objects in time and I am wondering if it's a feasible method at all. 
To be more precise I might want to digitally measure displacement in time of a swing for a kid, or do the same thing for dancers in order for them to sync better. Do you think computer vision may be a feasible method?

Comment: Yes! ...was that actually your question?

Comment: yeah, i didn't phrase that correctly - I am wondering explicitly what order of accuracy in measurement of x(t) and y(t) of small objects (but big enough to stick a sticker or IR diode to them) moving with acceleration up to  ~20 to 30 m/s^2 with camera placed around 10m in front of them.

Comment: Should be fine provided you have the right equipment and you spend the time to speed up your pipeline (e.g. using a high enough frame rate camera, moving the video reading into a separate thread/process than frame processing for tracking, etc). As far as accuracy goes, part of that depends on the quality of your camera and the robustness of the sticker/diode you use for tracking...but aside from that, you should be able to get accuracy in the measure of a few pixels.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot :)